# UITextView not showing formatted text from RTF File

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, rtf, resourcebundle

I am making an app for iOS 9.1 (using Xcode 7.1 and Swift 2.0), which contains a `UITextView` for displaying formatted text from an rtf resource file. I am calling the following function in the `viewDidLoad()` function of the view controller to load the text:

```
func loadTutorialText() {
    if let rtfPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("TutorialText", withExtension: "rtf") {
        do {
            let attributedStringWithRtf = try NSAttributedString(URL: rtfPath, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
            self.textView.attributedText = attributedStringWithRtf
        } catch {
            print("Error loading text")
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app, the text from the `rtf` resource file is loaded but everything is displayed as plain text. Here's an example of the test `rtf` file I'm using:

> **Example Heading**
>
> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
>   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
>   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
>   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
>   text text text text.
>
> **Example Heading**
>
> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
>   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
>   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
>   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
>   text text text text.
>
> *Bulleted List*
>
> - Item 1
> - Item 2
> - Item 3

Are there some properties I need to set for the `UITextView` to display this properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of setting the `documentAttributes` to `nil`, read them into a variable:

```
var d : NSDictionary? = nil
let attributedStringWithRtf = try NSAttributedString(
    URL: rtfPath, 
    options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType], 
    documentAttributes: &d)
```

**EDIT** Your RTF file works fine on my machine:

[image]

Literally the only code in that app is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tv: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let rtfPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("TutorialText", withExtension: "rtf")!
        var d : NSDictionary? = nil
        let attributedStringWithRtf = try! NSAttributedString(
            URL: rtfPath,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType],
            documentAttributes: &d)
        self.tv.attributedText = attributedStringWithRtf
    }
}
```

I would have to suggest that if that's not what you're seeing, you have *other* code that you have not told us about that's coming along and messing things up.

Comment: Thanks. I just made the change but it is still not displaying the formatting.

Comment: Can you post the rtf file somewhere? I'd like to try this myself.

Comment: Sure, here's a link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xz6lwp72kqpgexy/TutorialText.rtf?dl=0

Comment: Okay, works fine for me. See my revised answer. Something else must be going on.

Comment: Thank you for checking on this for me. As it turned out, I had a second font size setting for a different Size class added to the Font property in the Interface builder (left over from some previous experimenting). I later changed the Text property to Attributed, rather than Plain, in the Attribute Inspector, thinking that the previous settings wouldn't matter, but apparently, they were overriding the rtf code that I had. Removing the extra size class Font setting corrected the problem and it is working fine now. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. The technique I used is an important debugging device that should be in your toolbox: always, if something seems weird, I start again with a clean project and do just the minimum needed to test. That way, if my real project had other stuff that might be messing me up, I see how it works without that other stuff.

Comment: "but apparently, they were overriding the rtf code that I had" Yes, my book calls this out quite clearly: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_attributed_strings Look at the Note, where I say: "If you do decide to use attributed strings with an interface object, it is best not to mix in any of the pre-iOS 6 settings; if you’re going to use an attributed string, let it do _all_ the work of dictating text style features". Now you know why. Setting the `font` property manually strips away all the attributes from the attributed string. (And of course you did that in IB, which is kind of hidden)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95059/discussion-between-jason-o-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

Delete all font size settings for a different Size class added to the Font property in the Interface builder and the cause will eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 4

[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType]

don't work for me in swift 4

here is my solution:

```
let attributedStringWithRtf:NSAttributedString = try NSAttributedString(
                    url: rtfPath,
                    options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf],
                    documentAttributes: nil
                )
                self.textView.attributedText = attributedStringWithRtf
```